# Can't create rails application with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I run

rails new mothersapp -d mysql

```
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  ----- Some stuff here ------
      create  ----- Some stuff here ------
      create  ----- Some stuff here ------
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using .... some stuff here ...
Using .... some stuff here ...
Using .... some stuff here ...
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using multi_json 1.11.0
Using jbuilder 2.2.13
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/README.md
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:369:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:167:in `start'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:193:in `resolve'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/ayush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

How do I fix the error which I get at last? I am on ubuntu 14.04.
Creating a new rails application without mysql works fine. But, when I put mysql with a -d flag. I am getting this error. Can someone please explain what's the problem?

On running gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18' it gave :

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/README.md

Comment: Please try running `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'` and show the result

Comment: ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/README.md

Comment: there's an issue with the permissions in your /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ folder. Try doing `chmod -R ug+w /home/ayush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/`

Comment: This also doesn't work. Getting same error.